# Bootstrap 'row's not working but 'col's do

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

As the title says, I am pretty sure I set up bootstrap correctly and everything but running this page it shows me all the correct divs and and sized columns, however all the 'row' tags are ignored. they are just thrown all over the place. Shouldnt they be stacked one ontop of the other?

I really dont want to hard code positions, i want this to be responsive.

I have some CSS attatched to this but its the bootstrap giving me issues.

```
<body>
    {% block body %}
        <div class='row banner'></div>
        <div class='row header'>
            <div class='col-4 image'></div>
            <div class='col-8 bio'></div>
        </div>

        <div class='row profile'>
            <div class='col-3' style='justify-content: center; align-items:flex-start;'>
                Followers
                <div class='followers'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-6'></div>
                <div class='feed'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-3' style='justify-content: center; align-items:flex-start;'>
                Following
                <div class='following'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please correct HTML code like this.

```
<body>
    {% block body %}
        <div class='row banner'></div>
        <div class='row header'>
            <div class='col-4 image'></div>
            <div class='col-8 bio'></div>
        </div>

        <div class='row profile'>
            <div class='col-3' style='justify-content: center; align-items:flex-start;'>
                Followers
                <div class='followers'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-6'>
                <div class='feed'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-3' style='justify-content: center; align-items:flex-start;'>
                Following
                <div class='following'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

There is some mistakes in your code.
First of all div-end tag is missed before {% endblock %}.
Then, you mixed normal  tags and  tags inside the  tag.
This causes the breaking of your responsive style.

Comment: I noticed that error right after posting this, it was a mistake while trouble shooting. The rows however are still not right.

Comment: Please let me know what do you want exactly. Images would be helpful to understand your requirements.